# Why does fluid flow through an orifice under pressure not depend on fluid viscosity?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

The equation for fluid volume flow rate through a orifice is

$Q = CA\sqrt{\frac{2\Delta P}{d}}$

$C$ - discharge coefficient

$\Delta P$ - Change in pressure

$d$ - density of the fluid

$A$ - Area of the orifice

I was surprised to see that the flow rate does not depend on the *viscosity* of the fluid. Why is viscosity not a factor? Is the above equation only valid for some cases of fluid flows where viscosity does not affect the flow?

Is the fluid viscosity taken into account in the discharge coefficient?

Comment: How do you calculate the pressure drop term?

Comment: @SolarMike The equation is for fluid volume flow for a *given* pressure difference.

Comment: What is your discharge coefficient? Check out a Borda mouthpiece...

Comment: It does depend on viscosity but this effect is lumped into the discharge coefficient. For an ideal orifice (i.e. without viscous dissipation), $C = 1$.

Comment: @nluigi Can you add that as a answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score -1):

This equation is only valid in an ideal situation i.e. when there is no viscosity between the layers of the fluid.

For dynamic viscosity mu in fluids,

mu=Fy/Au,

where mu is the dynamic viscosity,
F is the applied force,
y is separation distance,
A is area of each plate
& u is the fluid speed.

So,

mu*u=Fy/A
mu*u*A=Fy

Therefore, A=Fy/mu*u

Substituting the value of A for the area of the orifice in the equation for fluid flow through an orifice, we can get an additional viscosity dependence part on the same equation.

**EDIT**: This does depend on viscosity but this effect is lumped into the discharge coefficient. For an ideal orifice (i.e. without viscous dissipation), C=1. (***AS SUGGESTED BY @NLUIGI***

It reinforces my previous statement.